# the best way to load images into android

Tags: php, android, android-recyclerview, out-of-memory

I have stored images as type 'image'(bytes) in Sql Server
now I would recuper it in my app android 
I try to send it as byte 64 to android but I had out of memory issue
I found some solution like to send the link of image from php and load it in android but I don't know how to get the URL of image(byte) and send it ?

RecyclerView adapter :

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.MyTag>{
LayoutInflater inflater;
DbConnection db ;
CnxExternal myConex = new CnxExternal();
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> listitem;
private CardAdapter.MyTag holder;
Context ctx;
ArrayList<byte[]> img , imgfou ;
ArrayList<String>nomesFo,descriptions;
String codeBar;
ArrayList<Integer>idfourns;



public CardAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list,ArrayList<byte[]>imagbyt,ArrayList<String>names,ArrayList<Integer>idf,String cod,ArrayList<String>Description,ArrayList<byte[]>imagfour) {
    super();
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.listitem = list;
    ctx=context;
    this.img=imagbyt;
    this.nomesFo=names;
    this.idfourns=idf;
    this.codeBar=cod;
    this.imgfou=imagfour;
    this.descriptions=Description;
    db =new DbConnection(ctx);

}

public class MyTag extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView price;
    TextView name;
    ImageView img;
    TextView namfou;
    TextView rating;
    FloatingActionButton btnlike;

    CardView cardView;
    public MyTag(View view) {
        super(view);
        //for animat
cardView=(CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

        price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.prixprodtestcard);
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nomprodtestcard);
        namfou=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qtestockcard);
        rating=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageprodcard);
        btnlike = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.likeButtoncard);
}
}


@Override
public MyTag onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, null);

    return new MyTag(v);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listitem.size();
}


@Override
public void onViewRecycled(MyTag holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    Glide.clear(holder.img);
}

public void onBindViewHolder(final MyTag holder, final int position) {

    //anim fadein
    YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInUp)
            .playOn(holder.cardView);

    final HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>)listitem.get(position);


    if(map.get("like").equals("0")){
        holder.btnlike.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
    }else{
        holder.btnlike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_liked);

    }
    holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ctx,InformationsProduit.class);
            i.putExtra("nomProd",map.get("name"));
            i.putExtra("prix",map.get("price"));
            i.putExtra("nomFour",nomesFo.get(position));
            i.putExtra("image",img.get(position));
            i.putExtra("telFour",map.get("telefournisseur"));
            i.putExtra("addrFour",map.get("adressFou"));
            i.putExtra("idFour",idfourns.get(position));
           i.putExtra("description",descriptions.get(position));
            i.putExtra("codeBar",codeBar);
            ctx.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    holder.price.setText(map.get("price"));
    holder.name.setText(map.get("name"));
    holder.namfou.setText(nomesFo.get(position));
    holder.rating.setText(map.get("rating"));


    Glide.with(ctx)
            .load(imgfou.get(position))
            //.diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.NONE )
            //.skipMemoryCache( true )
            .thumbnail(0.1f)
            .into(holder.img);


    holder.btnlike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        CardAdapter.MyTag hld=holder;
        int pos=position;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            HashMap<String, String> mapclicked = (HashMap<String, String>)listitem.get(pos);
            if(mapclicked.get("like").equals("0"))
            {
                hld.btnlike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_liked);
                mapclicked.put("like", "1");


                Snackbar snackbar;
                snackbar = Snackbar.make(hld.btnlike, "Bien ajouter au prefere", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
                snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                TextView textView = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                snackbar.show();

                db.insertFav(codeBar,idfourns.get(pos) , map.get("name") , map.get("price") , nomesFo.get(position) , map.get("adressFou") , map.get("telefournisseur") ,img.get(position) );

                hld.btnlike.startAnimation(animAdp());

            }else{
                hld.btnlike.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
                mapclicked.put("like", "0");

        Snackbar.make(hld.btnlike, "Removed from prefere" , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();

                db.deleteR(codeBar,idfourns.get(pos));
                hld.btnlike.startAnimation(animAdp());
            }
        }}
    );



}`
```

PHP function :

```
$res=sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);
while($res){

    while($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    array_push($information,array(
            ...
            "image"=>base64_encode($data['image']),

            "imgfour"=>base64_encode($data['imagefournisseur']),
                    ));

}
    $res=sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);
}
echo json_encode(array('produits'=>$information));

        }
```

******************Problem***********************
the problem was because of this big json file and big arraylist with images. Not of a recyclerview using twenty images. 
@greenapps

Comment: `as byte 64` ? base64?  `I had out of memory issue`. Where? On your server or in your Android app?

Comment: @greenapps in my android app

Comment: So, I don't know anything about `php`, but I think it's not very efficient to encode the image with `base64` and send it as json. I would try to create an url / a route to the image itself and send it unencoded as binary data to the client. This proposition may be old fashioned, but I don't see any benefit in using json here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you encoding a byte array to base64 string? Just echo the bytes. You dont have to make a file of the bytes on your server either as 
proposed in two answers.

A php script that outputs the bytes is as good as a direct link to an image file on a server.

Comment: thanks Mr @greenapps 
but how can I avoid the out of memory when I use bytes

Comment: Can you indicate where in your Android code you decode the received base64 string?

Comment: Are you putting twenty base64 encoded images in one json file? You could much better explain what you are doing. Please start explaining what your php script does.

Comment: ok Mr @greenapps
I receive 20 images bytes in the same Json file
and I put it into ArrayList<byte[]>images
I send the arrayList to my adapter in which I use the glide API to convert Byte[] to image View

 Glide.with(ctx)
            .load(imges.get(position))// byte [] 
           .thumbnail(0.1f)
            .into(holder.img);

Comment: Please put that info in your post. You should of course have started with that. Your memory problem is because of this big json file and big arraylist with images. Not of a recyclerview using twenty images.

Comment: yes Mr @greenaps it was very very helpful 
I removed the ArrayList of bytes and it  work 
but Could you give me an other solution to get all byte images from my database

Comment: You should make a php script that you call for every image and that just returns the bytes of one image. It should not make any difference if Glide uses an url pointing to an image file on your server. Or a php script that returns a requested image from a database.

Answer (score 0):

Better way would be to store your images on the server which can be accessed publicly using http like this image - https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/450103729383956480/Tiys3m4x.jpeg

When you have a path then you can use image loading libraries available for Android ( [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) , [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) , [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/)) to load it efficiently in your app without giving out of memory exception

Comment: thank's Mr @PassionDroid 
that's means that I will get a copy of image in my server

Comment: Yes and please accept it as answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I will get a copy of image in my DB and other one in the server is that good ?

Comment: If you use android libraries they will download the image and place it in the cache area of the app and not in sqlite database. Is there any specific need to place it in DB ?

Comment: yes 
if someone pressed 'like' to product it will saved in Sqlite

Answer (score 0):

you can use simply a link like this

https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/450103729383956480/Tiys3m4x.jpeg

form server and show in android then use " Picasso " image loading libraries

Comment: I try this solution but I still got out of memory when I receive more than 20 items